# ActionBarSherlock Custom Theme Being Ignored

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and have applied a custom them to alter the appearance of the action bar:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_action_bar</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/image_action_bar_logo</item>
</style>
```

This works perfectly on a device running jelly bean but when I deploy it on an emulator running 2.2 or 2.3 the custom action bar style is ignored and the default style is used.

Any ideas?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to adjust the theme and a little:

```xml
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <!-- define the style for ActionBarSherlock -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>

    <!-- define the style for native ActionBar for Android 4 and higher -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

Edit:

And also adjust the style appropriately:

```xml
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <!-- for ActionBarSherlock -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/background_action_bar</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/image_action_bar_logo</item>

    <!-- for native ActionBar for Android 4 and higher -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_action_bar</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/image_action_bar_logo</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, I also needed to have duplicate entries for the background and icon items without the android namespace.

Comment: Right, I added it to the answer.